OpenCV Intersection between Ellipses and and Line
I am trying to find the intersection points from an ellipses with a line.
I extract an ellipses from an image, and get the RotatedRect from fitEllipse. Now I paint several lines, and they (ideally) intersect with the ellipse. I need to find the intersection points.
This is basically the raw image.

I want to find those points.

Here would be some test vectors.
import cv2
import numpy as np

ellipse_center = np.array([439, 326])
ellipse_axes = np.array([int(283/2), int(565/2)])  
ellipse_angle = np.radians(91)  

line_point1 = np.array([583, 450])  
line_point2 = np.array([292, 115])  

window_name = "Demo"
cv2.namedWindow(window_name)
canvas = np.zeros((600, 800, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

while True:
    # Clear canvas
    canvas.fill(0)

    cv2.ellipse(canvas, tuple(ellipse_center), tuple(ellipse_axes), np.degrees(ellipse_angle), 0, 360, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.line(canvas, (293,115), (584,450), (0,0,255), 2)
    cv2.line(canvas, (70,290), (404,279), (0,0,255), 2)
    cv2.line(canvas, (59,353), (411,285), (0,0,255), 2)
    cv2.line(canvas, (463,272), (755,220), (0,0,255), 2)


    # Show canvas
    cv2.imshow(window_name, canvas)

    # Exit if 'q' is pressed
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Close OpenCV window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()


yeah, uh, transform the lines into the ellipse's coordinate frame, where it is actually a unit circle. then you can trivially calculate line-circle intersections, and transform those points back.

After posting the question and thinking about in in detail, I found a solution. Maybe a little bit hacky, but it works.
What I do is, I create a new image, paint the ellipse. Create a 2nd image, and paint the line. Then bitwise_and them, and see which point still is set.

better to show a step by step solution, with intermediate results than just stating how your method works

Make sure to use 4-connected pixel drawing to not risk missing intersections.
